# Card header background color on Angular2 materials

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I thought that it would be simple, but I'm struggling to set the background color of a card header within Angular2 materials and I'm not finding any examples.  Therefore, given the following code, I would appreciate tips on how to go about setting the background color of md-card-title:

```
<md-card>
   <md-card-header>
      <md-card-title>Title</md-card-title>
      <md-card-subtitle>Subtitle</md-card-subtitle>
   </md-card-header>
   <md-card-content>
       Body text
   </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

Answer (score 17):

Just add `[style.backgroundColor]="'COLOR_YOU_WANT'"` in your `<md-card-header>` selector:

```
<md-card>
   <md-card-header [style.backgroundColor]="'yellow'"> 
      <md-card-title>Title</md-card-title>
      <md-card-subtitle>Subtitle</md-card-subtitle>
   </md-card-header>
   <md-card-content>
       Body text
   </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

Link to [**working demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q4qzzh?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

Alternatively, add a class in your css file:

```
.custom-card {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

and set the `[ngClass]` in your `<md-card-header>` selector:

```
<md-card>
   <md-card-header [ngClass]="{'custom-card':true}"> 
      <md-card-title>Title</md-card-title>
      <md-card-subtitle>Subtitle</md-card-subtitle>
   </md-card-header>
   <md-card-content>
       Body text
   </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

or another alternative is to use `[ngStyle]`:

```
<md-card [ngStyle]="{'padding':'0px'}">
   <md-card-header [ngStyle]="{'background-color':'green'}"> 
      <md-card-title [ngStyle]="{'font-size':'24px'}">Title</md-card-title>
      <md-card-subtitle [ngStyle]="{'font-size':'12px', 'color':'white'}">Subtitle</md-card-subtitle>
   </md-card-header>
   <md-card-content>
       Body text
   </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

Comment: Shouldn't Material be able to interpret colors like "accent" or "warn"? What's the point in using a color scheme if you can't use it?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it doesn't honor the corner rounding.  It looks strange with a large white border in the header or footer as in the first two cards in the demo and if you remove the built-in padding you end up with traditional sharp corners as in the third card in the demo.  I would think the OP is looking for how to apply a background color while still retaining the mat-card styling (i.e. modern rounded corners), at least that's what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Either of these would help to set the header background:

1. Use `::ng-deep`

   ```
   ::ng-deep .mat-card-header {
       background-color: red !important;
       padding: 5px !important;
   }

   ::ng-deep .mat-card {
       padding: 0 !important;
   }

   ::ng-deep .mat-card-content {
       padding: 5px !important;
   }
   ```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Pki2MiHKZMAlGzDqFz6T?p=preview)

2. Use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` on components decorator an

   ```
   .mat-card-header {
       background-color: red !important;
       padding: 5px !important;
   }

   .mat-card {
       padding: 0 !important;
   }

   .mat-card-content {
       padding: 5px !important;
   }
   ```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/3SGQ0PIObVTDstECKXkp?p=preview)

Comment: You're right, the OP should inspect the DOM and detect, the style of which element He/She should change. For dynamically generated elements, which are not in component's HTML, we should use `::ng-deep` or `/deep/`.

Comment: I knew that `::deep` will be depricated, but didn't knew about `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`, thanks for the info!

Comment: Anyway, the life without `::ng-deep` and `encapsulation` will be really hard, we need the way to get access to shadow DOM (or how it's called correctly).

Answer (score 1):

Angular Material uses palettes, so there are two ways:

1. Overwrite theme colors right in the current palette (or create your own palette)
2. Use `!important` flag to override default colors (if this doesn't work without the flag, and in many cases it doesn't), like this: `md-card-title { background-color: green !important; }` (in some cases you will need `::ng-deep` as well to get access to those elements)

```
::ng-deep md-card-title {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

3. Use [NgStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) or [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

Answer (score 0):

you can set padding 0 to mat-card and set a padding to card inner element (mat-card-header, mat-card-content) :

`<mat-card style="padding:0">
    <mat-card-header style="padding:1rem; backgorund-color: blue">
        ...
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content style="padding:1rem">
        ...
    </mat-card-contetn>
</mat-card>`